# Create thread with specific privilege c++

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, multithreading

I have multi-thread application that I want to create a thread with different user privilege (for example : multi domain admin privilege).

but I can't find any Win32 API `CreateThread` to do that.

**How to create thread with specific user privileges?**

thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call CreateThread() with `CREATE_SUSPENDED` flag, then call SetThreadToken(), then ResumeThread().

Answer (score 2):

Call this from the thread that you want to have the specific user privileges, by logging on the thread as the specified user:

```
HANDLE hToken;
BOOL bRet = LogonUser("username","domain","password",
    LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
    LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,&hToken);
if(!bRet)
    // Add your own fault handling here
    return MessageBox(NULL,"Could not log on","Error",MB_OK|MB_ICONSTOP);
bRet = ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(hToken);
if(!bRet)
    // Add your own fault handling here
    return MessageBox(NULL,"Could not impersonate","Error",MB_OK|MB_ICONSTOP);
```

Comment: This would not work. Even if the process is impersonated, the newly spawned thread would be running in the parent process's user privileges. So creating the thread in suspended mode, setting the thread token (an impersonation token) and then resuming  (ResumeThread()) is the soln