# Impersonate and run any method using a logged in user context from SYSTEM level process (Windows Service):

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-services, impersonation

I have created a template class which will create a thread with logged-in user token and run any method. I passed it to the template class with the help of std::function and run it in the user level context.

**My Current Usage:**

1.The class is used in a windows service process ( which is running as SYSTEM level).

2.The thread is created in a suspended state and SetThreadToken() is used to apply the Impersonated token created from "explorer.exe". ( I know it is not a feasible way in multiple logged-in users case but for time being I need this thing to get work out).

3.After these I will resume the thread to execute the passed util method in user level context.

Referred thread impersonation from : [Create thread with specific privilege c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873782/create-thread-with-specific-privilege-c)

**Problem Facing:**

Successfully impersonated the logged-in user and the created thread also is running in user-level context (verified using **GetUserName()** API ) but the execution of any API from the method I have passed to the template class is not as expected. (Example: I have tried to read **HKCU** entry of the impersonated user but it is always failed with error: **ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. 2 (0x2)** ). 
**P.S:** Cross Checked the registry tree and the respective key is present there.

**NOTE:** The above example(**REG read**) is one of the util methods I have tried to pass to the Userimpersonator class and tried to run in user context from the service but in run time I will use this with any util method.

> UserImpersonator.h

```
class UserImpersonator
{

public:

    UserImpersonator();

    UserImpersonator(ImpersonationType typeVal,bool b_ImpersonateAndRunAsThreadNeeded = false);

   ~UserImpersonator();

    T1 ImpersonateAndRun(T2 callback_function);

    T1 ImpersonateAndRunAsThread(T2 callback_function);

private:

    ImpersonationType ImpersonationTypeVal;
    CString m_processname;
    HANDLE hToken;

    HANDLE impToken;

    bool m_ImpersonateAndRunAsThreadNeeded;

    T1 return_value;
    T2 callable_function_object;

    HANDLE hThread;

    BOOL InitializeImpersonation();
    BOOL RevertImpersonation();

    static DWORD WINAPI SpawnImpersonatedThread ( LPVOID lpParam );

};
```

> Method definitions:

```
template<typename T1,typename T2>
UserImpersonator<T1,T2>::UserImpersonator()
{
    ImpersonationTypeVal = ImpersonationType::IMPERSONATION_USING_WINLOGON;
    m_processname = _T("winlogon.exe");
    hToken = NULL;
    m_ImpersonateAndRunAsThreadNeeded = false;
    hThread = NULL;
    impToken = NULL;

    InitializeImpersonation();
}

template<typename T1,typename T2>
UserImpersonator<T1,T2>::UserImpersonator(ImpersonationType typeVal,bool b_ImpersonateAndRunAsThreadNeeded)
{
    ImpersonationTypeVal = typeVal;
    m_processname = (typeVal == ImpersonationType::IMPERSONATION_USING_WINLOGON) ? _T("winlogon.exe") : _T("explorer.exe");
    hToken = NULL;
    m_ImpersonateAndRunAsThreadNeeded = b_ImpersonateAndRunAsThreadNeeded;
    hThread = NULL;
    impToken = NULL;

    InitializeImpersonation();
}

template<typename T1,typename T2>
DWORD WINAPI UserImpersonator<T1,T2> :: SpawnImpersonatedThread ( LPVOID lpParam )
{
    TRY
    {
        UserImpersonator* ImpersonatorObject = (UserImpersonator*) lpParam;

        TCHAR   UserName[200] =  _T("");
    DWORD size = 200 ; //sizeof ( UserName ) ;
    GetUserName ( UserName  , &size  ) ;

    CString name = CString(UserName);

        ImpersonatorObject->return_value = ImpersonatorObject->ImpersonateAndRun(ImpersonatorObject->callable_function_object);
    }
    CATCH_ALL( e )
    {
        LogDebug ( _T("Exception occurs:%s"),__FUNCTIONW__ ) ;
        return FALSE ;
    }
    END_CATCH_ALL

return 0;
}

template<typename T1,typename T2>
BOOL UserImpersonator<T1,T2>::InitializeImpersonation()
{
    BOOL res = TRUE;

    try
    {
        TCHAR   UserName[200] =  _T("");
    DWORD size = 200 ; //sizeof ( UserName ) ;
    GetUserName ( UserName  , &size  ) ;

    CString name = CString(UserName);

        HANDLE process_handle = GetProcessHandleByName(m_processname);

        if ( OpenProcessToken(process_handle, TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, &hToken) == 0 )
        {
            res = FALSE;
            CloseHandle(process_handle);
            LogCritical(_T("%s : OpenProcessToken Failed with error-%d"), __FUNCTIONW__, GetLastError());
        }
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        LogDebug(_T("%s::Exception occurred"),__FUNCTIONW__);
    }

return res;
}

template<typename T1,typename T2>
T1 UserImpersonator<T1,T2>::ImpersonateAndRunAsThread(T2 callback_function)
{

    try
    {

        callable_function_object = callback_function;   

        hThread = ::CreateThread(0,0,SpawnImpersonatedThread,this,CREATE_SUSPENDED,0); //without using sb

        BOOL b = DuplicateTokenEx(hToken,MAXIMUM_ALLOWED,NULL,SecurityImpersonation,TokenImpersonation,&impToken);

        if( hThread )
        {
            if(SetThreadToken(&hThread,impToken))
            {
                DWORD thread_suspended_count = ResumeThread(hThread);

                if( thread_suspended_count == (DWORD) 0 || thread_suspended_count == (DWORD) 1 )
                {

                    DWORD thread_return_status = WaitForSingleObject(hThread,INFINITE);

                    if( thread_return_status == WAIT_OBJECT_0 )
                    {
                        LogDebug(_T("%s::SpawnImpersonatedThread successfully executed the callback function"),__FUNCTIONW__);
                    }
                    else
                        LogDebug(_T("%s::WaitForSingleObject failed with error=%d"),__FUNCTIONW__,GetLastError());
                }
            }
            else
                LogDebug(_T("%s::SetThreadToken failed with error=%d"),__FUNCTIONW__,GetLastError());
        }
        else
            LogDebug(_T("%s::CreateThread failed with error=%d"),__FUNCTIONW__,GetLastError());

    }
    catch(...)
    {
        LogDebug(_T("%s::Exception occurred"),__FUNCTIONW__);
    }

return return_value;
}

template<typename T1,typename T2>
T1 UserImpersonator<T1,T2>:: ImpersonateAndRun(T2 callback_function)
{
    try
    {
        return_value = callback_function();
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        LogDebug(_T("%s::Exception occurred"),__FUNCTIONW__);
    }

return return_value;
}

template<typename T1,typename T2>
BOOL UserImpersonator<T1,T2>::RevertImpersonation()
{
    if(hToken)
        CloseHandle(hToken) ;
    if(impToken)
        CloseHandle(impToken) ;

return RevertToSelf();
}

template<typename T1,typename T2>
UserImpersonator<T1,T2>::~UserImpersonator()
{
    RevertImpersonation();
}
```

> Example for Usage:

```
    UserImpersonator< bool,std::function<bool()> > ImpersonatedObj(ImpersonationType::IMPERSONATION_USING_EXPLORER,true);

    auto f = std::bind(&IsRegKeyExists);

    BOOL res = ImpersonatedObj.ImpersonateAndRunAsThread(f);
```

> Util Method:

```
bool IsRegKeyExists()
{
    HKEY phKey = NULL;
    bool res = false;

    is64bit = Is64BitConfiguration();

    CString subkey = _T("Volatile Environment\\USERPROFILE");

    if(is64bit)
    {
        lRes = RegOpenKeyEx( HKEY_CURRENT_USER, subkey.GetBuffer(), 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS | KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &phKey );
    }
    else
    {
        lRes = RegOpenKeyEx( HKEY_CURRENT_USER, subkey.GetBuffer(), 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &phKey );
    }

    if(lRes == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        res = true;
    }
    else
    {
       LogDebug ( _T("Key open failure! %d"), GetLastError() );
    } 
return res;
}
```

Comment: [*The RegDisablePredefinedCache and RegDisablePredefinedCacheEx functions disable handle caching for predefined registry handles. Services that use impersonation should call RegDisablePredefinedCacheEx before using predefined registry handles.*](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/SysInfo/predefined-keys)

Comment: but better use [`RegOpenCurrentUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regopencurrentuser) for Retrieves a handle to the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` key for the user the current thread is impersonating. and use this handle instead `HKCU`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER` this is [**Predefined Key**](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/SysInfo/predefined-keys) - this handles is cached:

> The `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` key maps to the root of the current user's
>   branch in the `HKEY_USERS` key. It is **cached** for all threads in a
>   process. Therefore, this value does not change when another user's
>   profile is loaded. `RegOpenCurrentUser` uses the thread's token to
>   access the appropriate key, or the default if the profile is not
>   loaded.

so you need first open user root key via  [`RegOpenCurrentUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regopencurrentuser) and use this handle instead `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`. also possible use [`RegDisablePredefinedCache`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winreg/nf-winreg-regdisablepredefinedcache) and [`RegDisablePredefinedCacheEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winreg/nf-winreg-regdisablepredefinedcacheex) in case you indirect access user registry hive